# Generating hyperbolic variates

Tags: distributions, random-generation

How do you simulate from the hyperbolic distribution? The Wikipedia article on it does not describe how to do so. I know that the hyperbolic distribution is a special case of the generalized hyperbolic distribution (GHD), and that GHD variates can be generated given normal and generalized inverse Gaussian (GIG) variates. But I am not too familiar with the GIG distribution and am hoping there is a simpler procedure for the "plain" hyperbolic distribution. In other words, what is the mixing distribution for the hyperbolic distribution?

Comment: The hyperbolic is a special case of the generalized hyperbolic (by setting $\lambda=1$) and of the generalized inverse gaussian (setting $p=0$). See the respective wikipedia pages for GHD and GIG. If you still need it, the wikipedia page for the hyperbolic suggests that the Barndorff-Nielsen reference gives the mixing distribution.